# JQuery: How to fetch the remaining HTML after removing elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having a very hard time using jQuery on a custom HTML object. I am searching an element and removing it and after that I need the remaining HTML but I am unable to do it. My code is below:

Ideally it should return `<div id="rendered"></div>` only.

```js
var data = '<h1 id="H9">Hi World</h1';
var html = '<div id="rendered">' + data + '</div>';

console.log($(html).find('#H9').length)
$(html).find('#H9').remove()
$('#view').html($(html).filter('#rendered').html()) // it shows h9 is there
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="view"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: Although chaining is fine, I would recommend you break this up so you get a better understanding of what you have at each step.   `var html = $(html);` then `html.find("#h9").remove();` will apply to the html variable whereas `$(thml).find..` will apply to a new jquery object based on html each time.

Comment: @mplungjan and?  Are we now not allowed to add additional information, written at the same time as your, personal, answers?   No one else seems to mind additional clarification or written in a slightly different way.  I had written an answer *at the same time*, but changed to a comment so I wouldn't step on your toes and you still complain.

Comment: No toes trodden… the smiley gave it away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not remove it from html, but from the unused object created by $(html)

Also you missed a > in </h1

```js
var data = '<h1 id="H9">Hi World</h1><h2>Keep this</h2>';
var html = '<div id="rendered">' + data + '</div>';

const $html = $(html); // now we have a jQuery object
$html.find('#H9').remove(); // remove the #H9
console.log($html.filter('#rendered').prop("outerHTML") )
$('#view').html(
  $html.filter('#rendered').prop("outerHTML") // insert the div
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="view"></div>
```

Comment: It does work, I was making a stupid mistake but I just wondered why it does not show empty div of `<div id="rendered"></div>`. It shows `<div id=view>` empty.

Comment: Nevermined, `filter` actually shows content of #rendered. But what if I want to show #rendered div too?

Comment: See updated code

Comment: Thanks, for some weird reason `console.log($html.filter('#rendered').prop("outerHTML"))` says `undefined` to me.

Comment: Not to me. See update - I use Chrome on Windwows